# How to add custom comments to google endpoint

Tags: google-app-engine, endpoint, google-cloud-endpoints, gae-eclipse-plugin

I am using the Google Eclipse Plugin to create an app-engine connected android app. From within the android project, I can only see generic meaningless comments about my endpoint methods. Is there a way to have my custom comments show?

(Recall that in eclipse you can see the Java docs of a method by placing the mouse on the method name.)

Here is an example of a generic comment:

```
Create a request for the method "register".
This request holds the parameters needed by the Pouton server.  After setting any
optional parameters, call the `Register.execute()` method to invoke the remote operation.
```

Comment: That *generic comment* is the Javadoc of the endpoint method, isn't it? You want to know how to change the Javadoc for the endpoint method?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Javadoc of an Endpoint method is like changing the Javadoc of any other method... See [**Oracle Javadoc documentation**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html) for more info.

Basically you have to go to the `.java` file with the source code of your Endpoint (if you generated the Endpoint automatically, the file will have the name `YourClassEndpoint.java`), and you just have to go to the method of which you want to change the Javadoc, and change the comment above the method.

Like this:

```
/**
 * Here is your generic comment, just delete this text and add your own...
 * It can be as long as you want...
 *
 * @param Here the explanation of the parameter "bar1".
 * @param Here the explanation of the parameter "bar2".
 * @return Here the explanation of the returned value.
 */
public Foo someMethod(Bar bar1, Bar bar2) {
    //...
}
```

Just by adding this kind of comment on top of a method, Eclipse (and other tools) will know that those comments represent the Javadoc and will display it properly...

Comment: Thanks for replying. I see how I can do that from within android itself. But each time I generate the endpoints, I would have to go and manually add all the docs. What I want is for the comments that I have on the server side to be the ones that show up when the endpoints are generated. As you might have guessed, I have comments in my endpoint class on the server side. They are not showing up on the android side. Instead, I am getting the default docs.

Comment: @PoutonGerald, ok, I was already thinking that the question was too obvious... Anyway, if you automatically generate the endpoints, you are generating them from a simple *pojo* class, right? So, do you really have to modify too many times the *pojo* class??